# Using Silhouette Score

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset that has 9 classes for each of its datapoints. For each of the images belonging to dataset, I pass it to ResNet50 and extract a 2048 feature vector by chopping the last later. I have saved the ResNet50 feature vectors each line for one data point in a txt file in the same order as my csv file.

I want to calculate the Silouhette score for each of these classes in my dataset. I am not sure how to move forward with my setup. I don't have much of code but here's a starter:

```python
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
from sklearn import cluster, datasets, preprocessing, metrics
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
df = pd.read_csv("master.csv")
labels = df['Q3 Theme1']
X = open('entire_dataset__resnet50_feature_vectors.txt')
X_Data = X.read()
print('Silhouette Score:', metrics.silhouette_score(X_Data, labels,
                                                    metric='cosine'))
```

I get this as an output: https://pastebin.com/raw/hk2axdWL

How can I fix this code so that I can print the single silhouette score?

```python
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have pasted one line of my feature vector file (a .txt file) here: https://pastebin.com/raw/hk2axdWL (consists of 2048 numbers separated by space)

Comment: Please make sure you can print your X, since X can be _io.TextIOWrapper', which cannot be passed to the function. Then it seems your labels should be reshaped to (-1,1) because it is 1D and your X is 2D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct answer, at least it worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics


df = pd.read_csv("master.csv")
labels = list(df['Q3 Theme1'])
X = open('entire_dataset__resnet50_feature_vectors.txt')
#X_Data = X.read()

fv = []
for line in X:
    line = line.strip("\n")
    tmp_arr = line.split(' ')
    print(tmp_arr)
    fv.append(tmp_arr)

print(fv)
print('Silhouette Score:', metrics.silhouette_score(fv, labels,
                                                    metric='cosine'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is coming from the line that you want to read `X`. I changed your code a little.

```py
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
from sklearn import cluster, datasets, preprocessing, metrics
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
df = pd.read_csv("master.csv")
labels = df['Q3 Theme1']
X = open('entire_dataset__resnet50_feature_vectors.txt')
X_Data = X.read()
print('Silhouette Score:', metrics.silhouette_score(X_Data, labels, 
metric='euclidean'))
```

Comment: This is the result I get when I run your code https://pastebin.com/NA9j5MLi so basically I want only 9 silouhette scores to be printed because I have 9 classes. My data in X has 1300 rows and 2048 numbers in each row because ResNet50 vector length is 2048.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to read your file.

The method requires an array as input, not a file handle.

Comment: please check Kiana's answer

Comment: Could you please check the updated question? I am not sure how to fix it

Comment: You need to learn how to properly read a CSV file into an array. Just calling `read()` on the file will give you a big strong,  not a data matrix.